# Why does iframe width appear as double what is specified in iOS on a retina display

Tags: html, ios, iframe, retina

I've set `width = 150px` for an iframe, but in iOS it has `offsetWidth = 300px`.

Does anyone know why, or how to fix it?

Comment: I had a similar issue with magnific popup. I fixed it giving fixed width in media query.

Comment: also had to fix width for the iframe content.